# Android, match the picture with dimension of the screen

Tags: android, layout, pixel, dpi

I have a picture of fixed height (60 px by  40 px).

I am trying to position the image by programmatically by adding margins to the image so that the image aligns to the center of the view

How I can get it done correctly to work for all different size and devices?

Comment: Your question would benefit from a diagram of what you're trying to achieve, more detail about the environment (Are you making an app? What with?) and an example of what you've tried in the context.

Answer (score 0):

Make the image have a width and height of wrap content and a layout_gravity of centerHorizontal

Answer (score 0):

You can make image params to match parent and then add margins of your choice.

```
       ImageView image = new ImageView(this); 
       params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
       params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
       image.setLayoutParams(params);
```